# What is the character limit for NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-developer

I was wondering what is the character limit in the message we set in **info.plist** when asking for Location Permission??

Comment: Did you try this for yourself ?

Comment: I wanted a character count to be specific but looks like its kind of unlimited. The description scrolls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen long texts in many apps (also seen on iOS guidelines here: 
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/app-architecture/requesting-permission/ )

plist doesn't have a hard limit, and if you write a text bigger than screen it scrolls automatically so it's safe to say there's no limit.